# how to access the information1 data

Tags: javascript

Am trying to access the data from the following JSON . Am Getting response after hitting the server and i need to access the data present in the information1 field.

```
{  
   "Test1":[  
      {  
         "id1":0,
         "Test2":[  
            {  
               "Information1":"info1",
               "name":"Testing",
               "defnitions":[  
                  {  
                     "displayname":"displayame"
                  },
                  {  
                     "displayname2":"displayame2"
                  }
               ],
               "information2":"info2"
            }
         ],
         "information3":"info3",
         "information4":"info4"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Do you already have a js object? is it comming from an Ajax response? You have to show us some code so we can understand the context.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: Currently Using angularjs and getting the response in the same format after hitting the service.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you are using square brackets, it means you have an array. Consequently, to access to your neccessary object you should use:

```
var data={  
   "Test1":[  
      {  
         "id1":0,
         "Test2":[  
            {  
               "Information1":"info1",
               "name":"Testing",
               "defnitions":[  
                  {  
                     "displayname":"displayame"
                  },
                  {  
                     "displayname2":"displayame2"
                  }
               ],
               "information2":"info2"
            }
         ],
         "information3":"info3",
         "information4":"info4"
      }
   ]
};
var yourObject=data.Test1[0].Test2[0];
```

To parse JSON response just use `stringify` method:

`var theWholeObject=JSON.stringify(data);`